# Let $f$ be continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $g$ be Riemann integrable on [a,b], then the integral $fdg$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove or disprove:

Let $f$ be continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $g$ be Riemann integrable on [a,b], then the integral $fdg$ exists.

My motivation to problem is studying the connections between the Riemann Integration and Riemann-Stieltjes integration, and trying to put conditions.

Comment: It may help (or not?) that $\int_a^b f \, dg$ exists if and only if $\int_a^b g \, df$ exists.